# How to encourage users to comment?

Tags: comments, motivation

My site is a webtoon comic. From my analytics there are a lot of people view and read comic but sadly only few of them leave a comment (only 5-10 comment on each chapter). Is there a way to encourage them to leave a comment?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot, or a link to the page?

Comment: It would be good to see a visual.

Comment: What do they gain from commenting?

Comment: @Mark When they post a comment, and many people like the comment they will get "best comment" tag and will be place at the top of the comment section.

Comment: I meant why should they comment

Comment: What % do you think should be commenting, and what are you basing that expectation on? Also, how do you know the content itself isn’t a factor?

Comment: As a word of warning, encouraging people to comment could result in a lot of garbage comments that provide little-to-no value.  Worse, such comments will decrease the signal-to-noise ratio.  Encouraging a response can lead to situations like "I don't know" "answers" to Amazon product questions.  If someone doesn't have anything useful to say, it's often better if they don't say anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

Screenshots would help to comment on the design/layout and how to encourage commenting.

Agree with Michael that understanding analytics better will help to guide your expectations and goals for comments.

As a copywriter, I'll say that 1) The content really matters. The more relatable, the more engagement. 2) There should be a clear CTA to comment (besides the native combox's own interface). In a blog, the latter is easy. You have some sort of conclusion or a subhead at the bottom: What's been your experience w/ X? Try to make it an open ended question over a yes/no question if you're looking for more engagement (if a CTA/ prompting question fits in your UI at all).

I'll also agree with Mark's question above about what do they gain from commenting? Is there a strong community, interesting comments/ conversation? Is there a form field that allows them to share their website link (and therefore a comment gets them a backlink)? You may not have any control over your combox set up, but if you can, I believe there are formats that could gamify commenting (e.g., someone who comments a lot gets a "super commenter" badge, that kind of thing). Another thing is that you could feature commenters who post something interesting. A podcast I listen to features one commenter/podcast reviewer everypodcast which functions to get people listening for their own name/business as well as tooting one's own horn about the podcast review. Once you get more momentum with comments, you might figure out a way to incorporate that kind of approach.

One last suggestion would be that once you get conversations going, feel free to call them out on social media, invite further comments to the blog by saying, "Hey there's a bit of a convo about X on my site today. What do you think? [link]".

Comment: Upvoted for mentioning the content as a factor.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Google Analytics - conversions]

First, **measure how many visitors convert into commenters**.

To borrow an old maxim from business and management:

> If you can't measure it, you can't improve it.

If you are using Google Analytics, you can use Conversions > Goals to track a goal -- this could for example be a 'thank you' URL the user is taken to after submitting a comment. In GA, this is known as a *destination goal*. See [how to add a  destination goal in GA](https://seriouslysimplemarketing.com/setting-up-destination-goals-on-google-analytics/).

Next, **try different things out and see if any of them increases the conversion rate**.

Examples of things to try:

- Change the language used in the 'Add a comment' link (or whatever it currently says)
- Increase the font size or weight of the text
- Change the text colour
- Change the link position
- Etc.

**Be realistic about your conversion rate.**

You haven't told us your conversion rate -- you've only provided the raw number of comments per chapter. While rates vary wildly, depending on context, design and other factors, [they tend to be single digit percentages](https://www.geckoboard.com/learn/kpi-examples/marketing-kpis/website-conversion-rate/).

For example, I'd guesstimate that a conversion rate (from comic strip reader to commenter) of around 2 or 3 percent would be decent.

Comment: Thanks, i haven't check the conversion rate yet, i just check the comment from each comic manually maybe i will start from that. And if rates are depending on context, how do you determine that the conversion rate decent?

Comment: Like I said, I am just guesstimating -- based on my own experience and also the generic benchmark for converting *anything*, which you can see in the link provided above.